# Scrape points from CTF sites

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-2.x, beautifulsoup

I am relatively new to classes. This one uses one.

I am pretty sure this is not the correct way to do this. But I also do not know the correct way.

You can use the `certified_secure` function when you make an instance of crawler that has the URL of hackthissite.org.

Do I have to many comments? Are they too verbose?

```
#! usr/bin/env python

import bs4
import requests

users = ['user1', 'user2']
certified_secure_url = 'https://www.certifiedsecure.com/profile?alias='
hack_this_site_url = 'https://www.hackthissite.org/user/view/'


# this function takes a string as input and outputs a list with all the integers in the string
def get_num(string):

    # get the numbers from string
    lst = ''.join([x if x.isdigit() else ' ' for x in string]).split()

    # change to list of ints instead of strings
    new_lst = []
    for item in lst:
        new_lst.append(int(item))

    return new_lst


class Crawler(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    # retrieve data from site and
    def get_site_data(self, user):
        request = requests.get(self.url + user)
        return bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')

    def certified_secure(self, user):
        experience = self.get_site_data(user).select('.level_progress_details')[0].getText()
        # get the points from the string
        return get_num(experience)[1]

    def hack_this_site(self, user):
        experience = self.get_site_data(user).select('.blight-td')[1].getText()
        return get_num(experience)[0]


# make to instances to crawl
cs = Crawler(certified_secure_url)
hts = Crawler(hack_this_site_url)

for user in users:
    print cs.certified_secure(user)
    print hts.hack_this_site(user)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension in `get_num`:

```
def get_num(string):
    """this function takes a string as input and outputs a list with all the integers in the string"""
    # get the numbers from string
    numbers = ''.join(x if x.isdigit() else ' ' for x in string).split()

    # change to list of ints instead of strings
    return [int(number) for number in numbers]
    # return map(int, numbers)  # Alternative
```

Also note that `join` can take a generator expression, so no need to convert to a list first. I also chose more descriptive variable names here.

You should also give your functions (and classes) a `docstring` (by putting a triple-""" delimited string as the first line of the funciton body, as I did above), which you can access interactively via `help(function_name)` and which is used by many documentation building tools.

It also seems a bit too manual to have to know which method to call depending on the url. Your crawler could decide that on its own:

```
class Crawler(object):
    sites = {"hackthissite.org": ('.blight-td', 1, 0),
             "certifiedsecure.com": ('.level_progress_details', 0, 1)}

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.options = self.get_sites_options(Crawler.sites)

    def get_sites_options(self, sites):
        for site, options in sites.items():
            if self.url in site:
                return options

    def get_site_data(self, user):
        """retrieve data from site and"""
        request = requests.get(self.url + user)
        return bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')

    def get_experience(self, user):
        select_str, index, out_index = self.options
        experience = self.get_site_data(user).select(select_str)[index].getText()
        return get_num(experience)[out_index]
```

Comment: `map(int, numbers)` looks really clean

Comment: @TristanT Yes, it's nice. It returns a `map` object though (some kind of generator), which is not always what you want. Can always surround it with `list()`, though. Some find `[int(number) for number in numbers]` better than `map(int, numbers)`.